# Error when testing new versions of Google Fit samples,

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-fit

Error when testing new versions of [Google Fit Samples](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-fit),

```
Process: com.google.android.gms.fit.samples.basicrecordingapi, PID: 22949
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.accounts.Account com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInAccount.getAccount()' on a null object reference
  at com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApi.zzagd(Unknown Source)
  at com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApi.zza(Unknown Source)
  at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zzbr.<init>(Unknown Source)
  at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zzbp.zzb(Unknown Source)
  at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zzbp.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
  at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

the methods have changed and I have noticed that since then, my application that uses the old methods does not register the data for DataTypes TYPE_ACTIVITY_SEGMENT, TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA and sometimes TYPE_HEART_RATE_BPM. What is the solution?

Comment: I notice you filed a [bug issue](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-fit/issues/28) in the GitHub. I'll leave it here so future readers will be updated.

Comment: Can you print which line of code in the sample is the exception getting triggered.